# Rails Internationalization and pretty URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, friendly-url

I just want to internationalize my Rails app, so URLs looks like: `site.com/en/products`.

What I did is:

```
# routes.rb
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|es/ do
  resources :pages
end

# application_controller.rb
def default_url_options(options={})
  logger.debug "default_url_options is passed options: #{options.inspect}\n"
  { :locale => I18n.locale }
end
```

But, with this, I get URLs like `site.com/products/?locale=en`. How can I get those pretty URLs?

Thanks.

Comment: this is weird, i have the exact same configuration and it works for me. i think this could be related to how you switch language. I use links like this : `<% link_to locale.to_s, url_for(:locale => locale.to_sym) %>` and it works

Comment: well, in my case i'm using it with `page_path('thepageiwant')`. How should I do it? (note: i'm using high_voltage for static page handling)

Comment: try `url_for :controller => 'pages', :id => 'thepageiwant', :locale => locale`

Comment: it's actually the same. what i want is the url to be properly 'prettified' (`site.com/locale/products`). with your suggestion, i still get `site.com/products?locale=en`

Comment: even with url_for ? this is weird. sorry but i'm clueless. maybe it's related to high_voltage, i don't know how the plugin creates its routes.

Comment: oh! it was my fault! everything worked as excepted. so much thankful!! you made my day! apart from that, do you know how to make `url_for` point to `en/about` instead of `en/pages/about`? I handled routing properly, but I don't know how to get the proper links. Thanks again!

Comment: sorry, but as i said, i don't know much about high_voltage routing. i copied my comment as answer.

Comment: it's not about high_voltage but about a `page` controller. I just want that links generated for certain controllers get this way `mysite.com/locale/action` instead of `mysite.com/locale/controller/action` (the `controller` is implicitly defined).

Comment: you could try to add `match "/:action" => "a_controller#:action"` at the end of your routes.rb (just before closing the locale scope). But be careful ! you have to add a constraint to :action in order to restrict the routes created to existing pages, or to define a method_missing on your controller to redirect_to 404.

Comment: yes, i did the routing: `match '/*id' => 'high_voltage/pages#show'`. the problem is how to use the helper url methods to generate proper urls, so when i use, for example, `url_for 'about'` -> `mysite.com/en/about` and not `mysite.com/en/pages/about`

Comment: have you tried `url_for :id => "mypage", :locale => locale` ? if this doesn't work honestly i don't know, and you should better ask a new question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3487/discussion-between-frarees-and-m-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
url_for :controller => 'pages', :id => 'thepageiwant', :locale => locale
```

Answer (score 3):

We use the i18n_routing gem to do that.

If you add it to your project you can do something like this in your config/routes.rb

```
localized do
  resources :articles
end
```

In your config/locales/nl.yml file: (for dutch routing)

```
nl:
  resources:
    articles: 'nieuws'
```

fallback will be /articles/:id. And dutch visitors get the /nieuws/:id url

Comment: but i want `www.site.com/nl` to be available, and also all the urls refering to the locale (`page_path 'news'` => `www.site.com/nl/news`). is that possible?

Comment: You can do that, but it's a bit of a hack [gist](https://gist.github.com/10afe73505d0da90e5d8)

Comment: wow that's strange for me! and yes, seems hacky. I've read the rails guide about internationalizing, and it talks about what I just want, but it seems for me that it's incomplete: [setting locale from url params](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params)

Comment: Hi, did you end up solving this?